# How to decode unicode text data back to excel file with or without php?

Tags: php, excel, unicode, phpexcel, file-encodings

Hello I'm trying to convert the encoded text data back to excel file.
I have an excel file(.xlsx), when it is opened in notepad, it show encoded text data. And I'm getting the data in the encoded text which I need to convert back to excel file.

I have an [excel](https://file.town/download/8b58w65da4k784ozpxmxcdwth)[-](https://file.town/stats/6c5hpwgrsedo9ho4rm2l0s1o5) file which when I tried to open in notepad it looks like: **(excel_file_txt.txt)**

```
 PK      ! ¤Y€¼ h  ¥    xl/worksheets/sheet1.xmlœ½[“ý¸qåû~>…

¢ßµE7Â!{bÔU¬[Ä‰s}î‘Ú–b$µCÝÏ|ûá®]õWe&2mIÑ’øC,®
XL ¿ý/ÿó/þÕÿøño?

ÿé§¿þãwëmùîW?þõ÷?ýáOý—üîÿýŽ_ïßýêç_~øë~øóOýñ¿û_?

þüÝù§ÿã·ÿþÓßþûÏüñÇ_~užà¯?ÿãwüå—ý‡ßüæçßÿñÇ¿üðóí§ýñ¯'ùçŸþö—~9ÿïßþå7?

ÿëß~üáïAùóo¶e‰¿ùËúëwÏ3üÃß®œã§þç?ýþÇ—Ÿ~ÿoùñ¯¿<Oò·ÿüÃ/çåÿüÇ?

ýëÏßýÓoÿð§“=þž_ýíÇþÇïþëú#8÷Ýoþé·ïuÿúñßþò¿õËÿíÿþñÏ?þþ—ÿpÞï~õøÓþÛO?

ý÷,ç¡åú{¼_Öÿù·_ýáÇþáßþüËÿõÓ¿ßüÓ¿üñ—ó$áòûŸþüóû?õ—?ýõýÌùá>køÓ~ùã

£Ø-­Kv)<îñÿúóïð÷ÿöó/?ýåÿÿ(òq
```

I tried to save this text file as using SAVEAS excelfile.xlsx & encoding as "UNICODE" (*I even tried other encodings like UTF-8, ANSII.*).

But when opened in excel it shows as: **(excel_file_txt_encode_save.xlsx)**

[image]

However, the original excel files looks like: **(excel_file.xlsx)**

[image]

Can someone help me to get back the excel file from the encoded text data or another way to get it done.

Comment: Why are you trying to open an xlsx file in notepad? The internal format of these files is zip compressed xml. You could try unziping the file to get the raw xml from it.

Comment: @JGNI - Actually I'm getting the data which looks same as when excel file is opened in notepad. Thing is I want to convert the incoming data (encoded form) back to excel (i.e in .xslx file)

Comment: OK so when you open it in Excel it's strange. Id the file type and file associations correct you can test this by running  the `assoc` and `ftype` programs from the windows command line.

Comment: My magic glassball says: The original file is a CSV file, not an XLSX file, that's why it "works" in Notepad.

Comment: @daxim - Thanks daxim, but the excel file link which is provided that's the same original file which is in .xlsx file if you checked the extension of it

Comment: If my guess is correct, then the extension is a lie.